# Do a startsWith in Hive HQL (with substring?)

Tags: hive, hql, hiveql

I'm trying to do a kind of Spark "**StartsWith**" in Hive. I have been reading to do this and what i found is to do it with a substring

I have a string, if this string starts with UTC8 I have to add this prefix UTC8-Min8 otherwise if it starts with PMM1 I would have to add the prefix NTC2-Min8 to an existing column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think if you remove double quote it should work. You have few syntax error though. COuld you pls try below code?

```
SELECT 
id, sum, address,
CASE 
  WHEN substring(trim(prd_ex),1,4) = 'UTC8' THEN CONCAT('UTC8-Min8',column_exe) 
  WHEN substring(trim(prd_ex),1,4) = 'PMM1' THEN CONCAT('NTC2-Min8',column_exe) 
END 
AS col_type
from Table1;
```

Comment: Hello Koushik, thanks for your help, it is working but it is duplicating the rows that meet the condition, that is, a row that does the CONCAT correctly and the same row in null, what could be happening?

Comment: Your data may have empty spaces in the beginning. so use `trim(prd_ex)`. i updated the SQL in my answer.